# What is $\mathbb Q (\theta)$ where $\theta$ is transcendental?

Tags: field-theory

Let $\theta \in \mathbb R$ be irrational.  Is $\mathbb Q(\theta) = \mathbb R$? What does $\mathbb Q (\theta)$ "look like"?

Comment: Assuming $\theta$ is trascendental, have you try to substitute it by an indeterminate $t$? Which elements can be constructed adding, multipliying and inverting with rational numbers and an indeterminate $t$?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

The rings (fields, in fact) map

$$\phi:\Bbb Q(\theta)\to\Bbb Q(x)\;,\;\;\text{determined by}\;\;\phi(\theta):=x$$

is an isomorphism.